# GOJS, Donut Chart around Node

Tags: javascript, donut-chart, gojs

I am trying to design a node template, In which it will have a donut chart around a node, like in the following example:

[image: This is the how I want it to look]

Node data will provide 5 values for 5 different attributes, and they will each be represented by a different color around node.

I have Seen the GoJs Pie-chart example https://gojs.net/latest/samples/pieCharts.html

And I am trying to add hollow circle in the pie-char, to make it look like donut chart. I Started from looking at the **Ring Shape** from GoJs Shapes https://gojs.net/latest/samples/shapes.html

So, I am modifying the function **makeGeo** from Pie-Chart example. and following is my Code.

```
function makeGeo(data) {
    var start = data.start;
    var sweep = data.sweep;
    var end = start + sweep;
    var param1 = 8;
    var w = 100;
    var geo = new go.Geometry();
    var rad = w / 2;

    var fig = new go.PathFigure(rad, rad, true);  // clockwise
    geo.add(fig);
    fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, start, sweep, rad, rad, rad, rad));

    var rad2 = Math.max(rad - param1, 0);
    if (rad2 > 0) {  // counter-clockwise
        //fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Move, rad + rad2, rad));
        fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Arc, end, -(sweep), rad, rad, rad2, rad2));
    }

    geo.defaultStretch = go.GraphObject.Uniform;
    return geo;
}
```

[This is my output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS5ge.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I am using GoJS version 1.6.15

Answer (score 0):

You're calling **PathSegment.close** twice.  I suggest you only call it the last time, not the first time.

Comment: using **PathSegment.close** once, or even without using it, made no difference. however commenting the following line made the output look a little close to target. `fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Move, rad + rad2, rad));`

Comment: I have updated the makeGeo function in question, now you can see the updated output. I think I am very close now, but have no idea how I can fix these thin lines...